# NodeJS Error In Constructor Language Only Present On Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I am trying to get a particular npm package to run on Ubuntu 16.04. I am currently running the most up-to-date versions of nodejs and npm, as well as the package (turndown).

Here is the error that I get:

```
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc1-01:/usr/server# nodejs index.js
/usr/server/node_modules/jsdom/lib/api.js:10
const { URL } = require("whatwg-url");
      ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at createHTMLParser (/usr/server/node_modules/turndown/lib/turndown.cjs.js:529:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/server/node_modules/turndown/lib/turndown.cjs.js:537:60)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
```

The error states it occurs within the "turndown" package and is due to the language in the constructor. What is confusing to me is that this runs on Fedora 27 without error.

What could be causing the difference in behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question was to update my version of NodeJS. I ran into another error now, but it is package related.